# Turning a list of letters into a list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, numbers, letter

I need to turn a list of numbers into a list of letters.

More specifically, I need to read `PZ` and turn it into `PZx`, such that the first distinct letter appearing in `PZ` assumes in `PZx` the number `1`, the second distinct letter assumes the number `2`, the third distinct letter assumes the number `3`, and the fourth distinct letter assumed the number `4`. Example:

```
PZ = ['R','O','B','O','R','R','B','G','O','G','B','G']

PZx = [1,2,3,2,1,1,3,4,2,4,3,4]
```

I need to write a function that turns any given `PZ` into `PZx` according to this rule.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary and [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), from the documentation:

> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with
>   a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

**Code:**

```
PZ = ['R','O','B','O','R','R','B','G','O','G','B','G']
uniques = {}
PZx = [uniques.setdefault(l, len(uniques) + 1) for l in PZ]
print(PZx)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [list index](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index) and have a simple loop like this

```
occured = []
for item in PZ:
    if item not in occured:
        occured.append(item)
    PZx.append(occured.index(item) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: PZ = ['R','O','B','O','R','R','B','G','O','G','B','G']

In [2]: d = {}

In [3]: PZx = []

In [4]: n = 1
In [5]: for x in PZ:
...:     if x not in d:
...:         d[x] = n
...:         n += 1
...:     PZx += [d[x]]
...:

In [6]: PZx
Out[6]: [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done easily with a dictionary. Try something like this.

```
PZ = ['R','O','B','O','R','R','B','G','O','G','B','G']
PZx = []
dict = {}
count = 1

for letter in PZ:
    if letter not in dict.keys():
        dict[letter] = count
        PZx.append(dict[letter])
        count+=1
    else:
        PZx.append(dict[letter])
```

now `PZx` should equal `[1,2,3,2,1,1,3,4,2,4,3,4]`

Comment: Can't you use `len(PZx)` instead of `count`?

Comment: Sure that would work, but i'm not sure on the implementation of len(). I would assume it would iterate through the list and count the elements which takes time. Using a counter guarantees constant time for the same functionality.

Comment: I think built-in containers store their lengths to be able to find their end point.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it by using pandas and list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

PZ = ['R', 'O', 'B', 'O', 'R', 'R', 'B', 'G', 'O', 'G', 'B', 'G']
PZ_unique = pd.unique(PZ).tolist()  # ['R', 'O', 'B', 'G']
PZx = [PZ_unique.index(pz) + 1 for pz in PZ]  # [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4]
```